# How to convert an array to object in mongodb query?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am new to mongodb and wanted to convert my array to object using pipeline. For example,

```
{
     field1: [1,2,3,4,5],
     field2: [‘a’,’b’,’c’,’d’,’e’],
 }
```

I want the above document to be converted to,

```
{
      fields: [
           {
                 field1: 1,
                 field2: ‘a’
            },
            ......
           {
                  field1: 5,
                  field2: ‘e’
            }
       ]
  }
```

Any idea how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) to separate your arrays.

And then format your new list with `$project` without forgetting to remove the duplicates created by the `$unwind`.

```
db.collection.aggregate({
  "$unwind": {
    path: "$field1",
    includeArrayIndex: "field1_index"
  }
},
{
  "$unwind": {
    "path": "$field2",
    "includeArrayIndex": "field2_index"
  }
},
{
  "$project": {
    "fields": {
      "field1": "$field1",
      "field2": "$field2"
    },
    "diff": {
      $cmp: [
        "$field1_index",
        "$field2_index"
      ]
    }
  }
},
{
  "$match": {
    "diff": 0
  }
},
{
  $group: {
    _id: "$_id",
    fields: {
      $push: "$fields"
    }
  }
})
```

Try it [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/STNt0ZPZU38)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [$zip](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/zip/) and [$map](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) and [$reduce](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/) to achieve this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$addFields": {
      fields: {
        $reduce: {
          input: {
            $zip: {
              inputs: [
                {
                  $map: {
                    input: "$field1",
                    as: "f1",
                    in: {
                      field1: "$$f1"
                    }
                  }
                },
                {
                  $map: {
                    input: "$field2",
                    as: "f2",
                    in: {
                      field2: "$$f2"
                    }
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          initialValue: [],
          in: {
            "$concatArrays": [
              [
                {
                  "$mergeObjects": "$$this"
                }
              ],
              "$$value"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/pp_UnPbQiTj)

Make sure both `field1` and `field2` are of equal length or you will lose some data.